# Is any possible to split string in Informix db 11.70?

Tags: sql, database, string, split, informix

I was searching already a while and still i am not sure there is any function to split string in Informix db 11.70? Should I write my own function to make my task real or I missed something?

Comment: A lot depends on on how you want to split the string. Can you be more precise about what want to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for SUBSTR function,

please refer to this page list of string manipulation functions:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0258.htm#ids_sqs_0258